# Setting the global elevation (z-axis) to a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-elevation

Is there any way to set a `View`'s elevation globally regardless of its parent `ViewGroup`, i.e. relative to the activity's root view? If it can be done with some native code that would be ok too.

I have a custom `View` that needs to show a badge within its bounds, however it is sometimes blocked and hidden by an overlay view.

I know I could just make the badge be part of a view that is on top of the overlay but I really want to keep the custom view and its logic all neatly tied up in one part of its code and layout.